# powershell indentation

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a large script that deploys an application. This script is based on several nested function calls.

Is there any way to "ident" the output based on the depth?

For example, I have:

```
function myFn()
{
    Write-Host "Start of myfn"
    myFnNested()
    Write-Host "End of myfn"
}
function myFnNested()
{
    Write-Host "Start of myFnNested"
    Write-Host "End of myFnNested"
}

Write-Host "Start of myscript"
Write-Host "End of myscript"
```

The output of the script will be :

> ```
> Start of myscript
> Start of myfn
> Start of myfnNested
> End of myFnNested
> End of myFn
> End of myscript
> ```

What I want to achieve is this output :

> ```
> Start of myscript
>   Start of myfn
>     Start of myfnNested
>     End of myFnNested
>   End of myFn
> End of myscript
> ```

As I don't want to hardly code the number of spaces (since I does not know the depth level in complex script). How can I **simply** reach my goal ?

Maybe something like this?

```
function myFn()
{
    Indent()
    Write-Host "Start of myfn"
    myFnNested()
    Write-Host "End of myfn"
    UnIndent()
}
function myFnNested()
{
    Indent()
    Write-Host "Start of myFnNested"
    Write-Host "End of myFnNested"
    UnIndent()
}

Write-Host "Start of myscript"
Write-Host "End of myscript"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this script http://poshcode.org/scripts/3386.html

If you load up that Write-Verbose wrapper, you can set `$WriteHostAutoIndent = $true` and then just call Write-Host and it will be indented based on stack depth.  So given these functions as you defined them originally:

```
function myFn()
{
   Write-Host "Start of myfn"
   myFnNested
   Write-Host "End of myfn"
}
function myFnNested()
{
   Write-Host "Start of myFnNested"
   Write-Host "End of myFnNested"
}
```

With no changes, you can just dot-source a script file with that Write-Host wrapper function in it:

```
C:\PS> . C:\Users\Jaykul\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\PoshCode\3386.ps1
```

And then merely set the preference variable before you call your function:

```
C:\PS> $WriteHostAutoIndent = $true
C:\PS> myFn
  Start of myfn
    Start of myFnNested
    End of myFnNested
  End of myfn
```

Beautiful indented output, like magic ;-)

Comment: How do you find time to write such great scripts? :)

Comment: There's a link to this script on github, in case anyone else is looking for it: https://github.com/PoshCode/poshcode.github.io/blob/data/scripts/3386.md

Answer (score 7):

You could use a wrapper function around `write-host` which used `$MyInvocation` to determine the stack depth to create a number of spaces to prefix the message.

Combine this with the `-scope ‹n›` parameter of `Get-Variable` to pull out each calling level… something like the `showstack` function adapted from *Windows PowerShell In Action* (Payette, 1<sup>st</sup> Ed):

```
function ShowStack {
  trap { continue; }
  0..100 | Foreach-Object {
    (Get-Variable -scope $_ 'MyInvocation').Value.PositionMessage -replace "`n"
  }
}
```

You'll need the maximum value of `$_` in the pipeline before `Get-Variable` fails for scope count being too high.

Comment: Hmm... though the solution from here is obvious to some, it might not so obvious to everyone... OK, maybe it is just me having a mental block. How does one adapt the idea presented into a write-host wrapper function?

Comment: @msorens The basic idea here is looping up the stack, relying on `Get-Variable` to throw when it reaches the top of the stack. For this case it would be a matter of filtering `$MyInvocation` values which represent a stack frame where you want an extra level of indentation (eg. each one that is an invocation of `MyRecursiveFunction`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Console.CursorLeft to set its position. Be aware that write-output will reset any custom location, so you need to reset it after each output. Here is a sample:

```
    $i = 0
    function Indent() {
        [console]::CursorLeft += 2
        $i = [console]::CursorLeft
        $i
    }

    function UnIndent() {
        if($i -gt 0) { $i -= 2 }
        [console]::CursorLeft = $i
        $i
    }

    function WriteIndent([string]$s) {
        [console]::CursorLeft += $i
        write-host $s
        # Reset indent, as write-host will set cursor to indent 0
        [console]::CursorLeft += $i
    }

    function myFnNested() {     
      $i = Indent     
      WriteIndent "Start of myFnNested"     
      WriteIndent "End of myFnNested"     
      $i = UnIndent 
    }

    function myFn() {     
      $i = Indent   
      WriteIndent "Start of myfn"     
      myFnNested
      WriteIndent "End of myfn"     
      $i = UnIndent 
    } 

    WriteIndent "Start of myscript"
    myFn
    WriteIndent "End of myscript"
```

Output:

```
    PS C:\scripting> .\Indent-Output.ps1
    Start of myscript
        Start of myfn
            Start of myFnNested
            End of myFnNested
        End of myfn 
    End of myscript
```

Comment: you can do this a bit more neat by using a function that will indet a certain amount:
`function Write-Help
{
    param(
        [string]$output,
        [int]$indents=0
    )

    $indentSize = 2

    [console]::CursorLeft += $indentSize * $indents
    Write-Host"$output"
}`
 and then just call `Write-Help "my help" 2` instead of resetting the cursor for every output. Sorry about the formatting, comments don't allow line breaks, but I don't think this warrants a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Write a DEBUG function. Two arguments, one is a flag that takes Start, Stop, or Note; the other argument should be the debug text. (I'd use 1, -1, and 0 for the flag, then you can just add the flag to a Indent variable to set increment depth. Stupid but good enough for debugging.)

Answer (score 0):

I used another line of thinking.  I set a count variable that is incremented at the start of the function and then used the following code to pad the line I was writing:

```
write-host ($string).PadLeft( ($string).length + (2 * $count) )
```

This will indent two spaces for every recursion.

Comment: Bad approach, this has to be repeated for each write-host call. Keep it DRY https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Write-Host` to write your indents before calling the original with the '&' operator and the namespace. You might be able to derive the amount of indentation from the current stack scope, but a global variable gives you more control.

```
$global:writeHostIndent

function Write-Host
{
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host (' ' * $global:writeHostIndent) -NoNewline
    & 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host' $args
}
```

Comment: the `& 'Microsoft..\WriteHost' $args` doesnt seem to parse args correctly for me, I end up with any other options that I passed at the command line being part of the message.