# Indent output from private functions in Powershell

Tags: powershell, indentation

I have a bunch of functions that I call that produce output that is displayed to the console. Functions might look something like the following:

```
exec { & .\xunit.console.clr4 tests.xunit }

#or

exec { & .\nuget.exe pack $source_dir\ZocMonLib\NuSpec\ZocMon.nuspec -OutputDirectory $build_dir\local -Symbols -Version $version }
```

Now I know I could do something like [powershell indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532324/powershell-indentation) but that only works if I control the output.

How do I do the indenting of output for these private functions?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I wrote a version that does the line wrapping right. But it's slightly complicated. I posted it on PoshCode http://poshcode.org/3386

That should work for Write-Host or Write-Verbose, but it will *not* work if those functions are actually outputting objects -- you'd have to pipe to Write-Host.

The function on PoshCode will (optionally) auto-indent based on the stack depth, but also allow you to specify `-Pad 5` or something to manually indent, so you can call `nuget.exe ... | write-host -pad 5` or just stick `| Write-Host` wherever you need it, and then set `$WriteVerboseAutoIndent = $true` ...

Hope that helps -- it does do manual line wrapping on the output of exes, so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a great solution, because PowerShell doesn't always run in the console window. Other hosting applications might or might not support tab characters, and might not even support Write-Host. If your goal is strictly to support console display, consider writing a "Format-Console" function.

```
nuget list NuGetPowerTools | Format-Console
```

Inside that function, you can capture the pipeline input (which I presume would be strings since this is an external command). Each line of output would be a single String object, so...

```
Write-Host "    $x"
```

Would display that indented by four spaces.

```
function Format-Console {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string[]]$inputObject)
    PROCESS { Write-Host "    $inputObject" }
}
```

That's kinda quick and dirty, but assuming you only ever pipe strings to it, it'll work. Building this as a function lets it be more reusable; using the Format- verb cues other users that the output of this isn't intended to be consumable. It technically isn't a true "Format" cmdlet since it doesn't output internal formatting directives, but it's consistent with the usage pattern for

Comment: As @Jaykul says the problem I now have is line-wrapping. Anyone got any ideas on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you assign the result of your private functions to a string and "tab" that string?

```
$x = nuget list NuGetPowerTools
Write-Host "`t`t$x"
```